# Is there an ag-grid header cell class?

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to specify a css class to ag-grid header row/cells without custom render? I just want all the column headers to have padding-left = 8px

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by CSS

```
    .ag-cell-label-container .ag-header-cell-label {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
```

Check this live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/P7QyIXZfKKpqH1AIwDKp?p=info

Have another CSS selector if you'd like to have only to a specific [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) for your application.